# MySQL Occasionally Returns Wrong Value

Tags: php, mysql

This is a general question, one that I've been scratching my head on for a while now.  My company's database handles about 2k rows a day.  99.9% of the time, we have no problem with the values that are returned in the different SELECT statements that are set up.  However, on a *very* rare occasion, our database will "glitch" and return the value for a completely different row than what was requested.

This is a very basic example:

```
+---------+-------------------------+
| row_id  | columnvalue             |
+---------+-------------------------+
|       1 | 10                      |
|       2 | 20                      |
|       3 | 30                      |
|       4 | 40                      |
+---------+-------------------------+

SELECT columnvalue FROM table_name WHERE row_id = 1 LIMIT 1
```

**Returns:** 10

But on the *very* rare occasion, it may return: 20, or 30, etc.

I am completely baffled as to why it does this sometimes and would appreciate some insight on what appears to be a programming phenomena.

More specific information:

```
SELECT
  USERID, CONCAT( LAST, ', ', FIRST ) AS NAME, COMPANYID 
FROM users, companies 
WHERE users.COMPANYCODE = companies.COMPANYCODE 
AND USERID = 9739 LIMIT 1

mysql> DESCRIBE users;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| USERID     | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| COMPANYCODE| varchar(255)| NO   | MUL |         |                |
| FIRST      | varchar(255)| NO   | MUL |         |                |
| LAST       | varchar(255)| NO   | MUL |         |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE companies;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| COMPANYID  | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| COMPANYCODE| varchar(255)| NO   | MUL |         |                |
| COMPANYNAME| varchar(255)| NO   |     |         |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What the results were suppose to be: 9739, "L----, E----", 2197
What the results were instead: 9739, "L----, E----", 3288

Basically, it returned the wrong company id based off the join with companycode.  Given the nature of our company, I can't share any more information than that.

I have run this query 5k times and have made very modification to the code imaginable in order to generate the second set of results and I have no been able to duplicate it.  I'm not quick to blame MySQL -- this has been happening (though rarely) for over 8 years, and have exhausted all other possible causes.  I have suspected the results were manually changed after the query was ran, but the timestamps states otherwise.

I'm just scratching my head as to why this can run perfectly 499k out of 500k times.

Comment: Is `row_id` the primary key column? A unique-indexed column? Neither?

Comment: row_id would be the primary key for this example.  But in some cases, it's an indexed column.

Comment: Are you saying that you can run this query from the workbench 100 times and once it will return a different value? Or that you have some code generating the query in question (which perhaps is dynamic itself and perhaps suspect)? If you can reproduce such a simple query failing with any regularity that would be a massive bug that would cripple MySQL users of all types... which makes me suspect that there is more left unstated.

Comment: In the most recent case, it is a dynamic query with a join that runs approximately 1k times a day.  If the dynamic value (numerical) isn't correct, the query doesn't work at all and an error report is generated.  In this case, the query ran and pulled up the correct results from one table (primary key, string), but pulled up the wrong result from the second (primary key).  This happens maybe once every 500k queries.

Comment: You're not showing the actual table structure, queries or related code. It's hard to even theorize about possible causes from such a generic description.

Comment: Going to agree with DCoder. The fact this is a dynamic query with a join *that you haven't shared* means I would put 99.9999% odds against it being MySQL at fault. Share the information to help us help you: currently this question implies that MySQL is flawed in a horrific way, but hides the user code that is actually at fault behind a false static SQL statement.

Comment: I'm currently trying to compile the code and make the necessary changes for security reasons.

Comment: try doing it like this to ensure it starts at 0 LIMIT 0,1

Comment: Why have you got a `LIMIT 1` when the column you're comparing with a constant is a primary key and therefore only returns one matching record? Is there something else you're leaving out?

Comment: I'm not leaving out anything.  I often use a LIMIT 1 in a query when I only need one row returned.

Answer (score 3):

Now that we have a more realistic query, I notice right away that you are joining the tables, not on the primary key, but on the company code. Are we certain that the company code is being enforced as a unique index on companies? The Limit 1 would hide a second row if such a row was found.

From a design perspective, I would make the join on the primary key to avoid even the possibility of duplicate keys and put company code in as a unique indexed field for display and lookup only.

Comment: I am 100% positive the company code values are unique.  And when removing the LIMIT 1, it is still returning the correct results and not the incorrect ones that were generated earlier.

And there are plans to modify these tables in the future to switch to primary keys when referencing joins.

Comment: @L.Krecic: 1) unless you can reproduce this problem at will, you cannot say that removing `LIMIT 1` still returns the correct results. 2) you really should have a unique index on the company code as well as a foreign key to enforce the relation (and of course InnoDB). 3) can you remove `LIMIT 1` from the in-code query, add code to detect if one or more rows were returned, and log a lot of info when multiple rows are returned?

Comment: In that case your suspicion that the data may be changing under you may still be true. Assuming uniqueness is not enforced on COMPANYCODE, you may be seeing a duplicate row being introduced and then later removed. This might even happen in a short window (but not within a transaction) which would match your experience.

For example, you might have a module that allows companies to be added, adds the duplicate and then discovers the issue and backs out the record. The interval between the insert and removal would act as described, especially with the LIMIT 1 in place.

Comment: @Godeke The companies table does not accept duplicate companycode values at the time of creation.  When a companycode string is generated, the software checks to make sure there is no duplicate value in the table _before_ it is inserted.

Comment: @DCoder Setting up a log is possible, but given that this happens maybe 3 times a year, it may not come up again until well into 2014.  Whether the query has a LIMIT or not, the query referenced a unique alphanumeric value (companycode) and returned the wrong primary key.

Comment: The insert/removal cycle was just an example, and frankly without a unique constraint I'm not sure where the assurance that a duplicate *is* made (and potentially violated). Regarding the "limit or not", I really don't buy into that as someone put the limit on there to probably avoid having the single row expectation from being violated.

Again, without more data (table schema, code that creates the rows, etc), I think this has reached an impasse.

Comment: @Godeke It's just a coding practice of mine to put a LIMIT to my queries (I also included it in my first example query), even if I'm only expecting one row to be returned.  I'm not trying to be sneaky here.  If I had known it was going to essentially the sole focus of much of the comments on this post, then I would have left it out.  And I understand that a non-unique companycode would completely explain a wrong return on the primary key.  But I am 100% positive the value was unique at the time of the query.

Comment: You can't be positive if you don't have the `UNIQUE` constraint. If you think checking whether something exists in the database using PHP, then you're sadly wrong. Unless you put a constraint there, you can't **safely** assume there aren't duplicates. But, your project, your call.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is either due to an incredibly *unlikely* SERIOUS bug in MySQL, -or- MySQL is returning a result that is valid at the time the statement is run, and there is some other software that is garfing up the displayed result.

One possibility to consider is that the row had been modified (by some other statement) at the time your SQL statement executed, and then the row was changed again later. (That's the most likely explanation we'd have for MySQL returning an unexpected result.)

The use of the `LIMIT 1` clause is curious, because if the predicate uniquely identifies a row, there should be no need for the `LIMIT 1`, since the query is guaranteed to return no more than one row.

This leads me to suspect that `row_id` is not unique, and that the query actually returns more than one row. With the LIMIT clause, there is no guarantee as to which of the rows will get returned (absent an ORDER BY clause.)

Otherwise, the most likely culprit is out dated cache contents, or other problems in the code.

---

### UPDATE

The previous answer was based on the example query given; I purposefully omitted the possibility that `EMP` was a view that was doing a JOIN, since the question originally said it was a table, and the example query showed just the one table.

Based on the new information in the question, I suggest that you OMIT the `LIMIT 1` clause from the query. That will identify that the query is returning more than one row.

From the table definitions, we see that the database isn't enforcing a UNIQUE constraint on the COMPANYCODE column in the COMPANY table.

We also know there isn't a foreign key defined, due to the mismatch between the datatypes.

Normally, the foreign key would be defined referencing the PRIMARY KEY of the target table.

What we'd expect the `users` table to have a `company_id` column, which references the `id` (primary key) column in the `companies` table.

(We note the datatype of the `companycode` column (`int`) matches the datatype of the primary key column in the `companies` table,  and we note that the join condition is matching on the `companycode` column, even though the datatypes do not match, which is very odd.)

Comment: The odds of this being a MySQL bug are extremely low. That should be the last thing one investigates.

Comment: @tadman: you are correct, I concur that the chance that that this is a MySQL bug are very low. Just didn't want to leave that possibility out.

Comment: People are quick to blame their tools, like those that insist ever error in their program is a "compiler error". For all practical purposes, MySQL bugs do not exist. Undefined behavior when using it incorrectly, though, or having unreasonable expectations is all too common.

Comment: "join condition is matching on the companycode column, even though the datatypes do not match, which is very odd..."  This was actually my mistake.  I had to type the table layout by hand and make changes to it for security reasons.  The company code column for both tables is the same data type.  Also, the company code values are all unique, I am 100% certain about this.  In addition, when running the query without the LIMIT, I still get 1 row returned and it is the correct value, not the incorrect one that was generated earlier.

Comment: Absent a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `COMPANYCODE` column in the `company` table, you don't have any guarantee that there wasn't more than one row with that same value at the time your query runs. If you did have that guarantee, there would be no need for the `LIMIT 1` clause, since the equality predicate on the primary key of the `user` table guarantees no more than one row will be returned. It just smells (to me) like someone added the `LIMIT 1` to that query to partially mask a problem with the database design. If it returns more than one row, maybe you want your app to throw an exception

Comment: @spencer7593 As I said in other comments, when a new companycode (alphanumeric value) is generated, the companies table is checked for a duplicate value _before_ it is inserted.  Inserts are made into the companies table about 10 times a week by only one person.  Secondly, I always use a LIMIT 1 on a query when when I only need one row returned, even if it's only going to return one row in the first place.  If I had known everyone was going to focus on it so much, I would have left it out of my initial post.

Comment: The reason people are fixating on LIMIT 1 is that it is commonly used to mask a problem with relationships not having unique constraints. Hiding it would have masked a potential source for the problem... and unfortunately the help you get is directly tied to the honesty of the posted problem compared to the actual configuration. Diagnosing *another, unrelated configuration* isn't going to go very far towards the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons this could happen. I suggest you look at the assumptions you're making. For example:

- If you're using `GROUP BY` and one of the columns isn't an aggregate or the grouping expression, you're going to get an unpredictable value in that column. Make sure you use an appropriate aggregation (such as `MAX` or `MIN`) to get a predictable result on each column.
- If you're assuming a row order without making it explicit, and using `LIMIT` to get only the first row, the actual returned order of rows differs depending on that result's execution plan, which is going to differ in large resultsets based on the statistics available to the optimiser. Make sure you use `ORDER BY` in such situations.